# AWS cli is asking for secret key and access key Id even though right IAM role is attached to the instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have an ec2 instance which has the IAM role attached to it for creation of EC2 instances. It also has aws cli installed.

I am trying to use cloudformation cli command to create a stack based on a json template in s3. But it's asking me to provide accessKeyId and secret key etc which I do not have as I do not want to create any IAM user.

Is there any workaround to this ?

Here is the command which I am using:

```
aws --region us-east-1 cloudformation create-stack --stack-name myteststack --template-url https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/object/aws-cli-test11/test_ct.json?region=us-east-1&tab=properties --parameters ParameterKey=KeyName,ParameterValue=eai_ec2user,ParameterKey=InstanceType,ParameterValue=t2.medium
```

EDIT----------

I receive the error messaage **Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".**  on all aws cli commands. I tried below command and got the same error.:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=availability-zone,Values=us-east-1a"
```

The question is why it's not using the IAM role which is assigned to the instance. That role is having all the necessary policies attached.

The commands are working fine under root user but not under non root user. All the above errors are for non root users.

Comment: What is the text of the error message you are seeing?

Comment: Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
This is the error message. Also, I receive this error on all aws cli commands.

Comment: From the info you've provided so far, it seems that you are able to run awscli commands as the root user but not as a non-root user. That could be because your root user can retrieve credentials from the EC2 metadata service but your non-root user cannot. You should be able to run: curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/info. If this works as root but not as a non-root user then I suspect you have some kind of iptables rule that blocks non-root users from reaching the metadata service at http://169.254.169.254. Is that possible?

Comment: @Jarmod.... Thanks. That was absolutely correct. The above command works from root user but not from non root user.

Is there a way I can configure iptable to allow a particular non root user to access the metadata ?

Comment: How are you currently implementing the 'drop traffic' rule for non-root users? And it's worth asking, do you actually need to drop this traffic? How does your application operate in the absence of network? Can you move this firewalling to EC2 Security Groups instead of iptables?

Comment: There is no 'drop traffic' rule. Everything is set to default.

Below is the content in iptable:

[root@ip-10-XX-1-XXX ~]# iptables -L

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
[root@ip-10-XX-1-XXX ~]#

Comment: Something non-default is happening on your EC2 instance. Are you using a custom AMI, or do you have custom bootstrap scripts? I would be tempted to launch a second EC2 instance, preferably from a standard Amazon-supplied Linux AMI, with the same IAM role and verify that the default user (ec2-user or ubuntu) can use awscli. This should work and might help you diagnose why your original instance is non-standard.

Comment: Yes. I am using a custom ami. I will test it out using a standard amazon ami. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Turns out everything works fine in my personal account but things start to mess up (like above errors) when I do it on the corporate account of my organisation. I think somehow the metadata access is blocked via some proxy for non root users.

Comment: May be worth talking to your company sysadmins to understand why this is happening.